# How to only fill the color of a rounded rectangle and keep it in a var in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I'm working on the interface of my programe and I just recently was able to draw what I want. I have a certain number of rounded rectangle with a number in the middle of each one, but I can't figure out how I can just have those rectangle filled with a certain color and now border line. In addition to that, i would need to to stock each rectangle inside a var to be able to change the color of the rectangle. Here is my code so far:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameNumView extends JPanel
{
    //Nombres affiché
    String[] Numbers;

    public GameNumView(int pWidth, int pHeight)
    {
        //Change ajuste la grosseur du panel
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pWidth, pHeight));

        //Crée le tableau des strings
        Numbers = new String[]{};
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        //Repain avec la super class
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Calcule les dimensions qui seront utilisé
        int rectSpace = 5;
        int rectWidth = getWidth()/Numbers.length-rectSpace*2;
        int rectHeight = getHeight()-rectSpace*2;
        int arcRect = 15;

        int fontSize = 60;
        int textX = rectWidth/2 - fontSize/4 - rectSpace;
        int textY = rectHeight/2 + fontSize/2 - rectSpace;

        //Change al font
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));

        //Dessine un rounded rectangle avec le nombre pour chaque chiffre du tableau
        for(int i =0; i < Numbers.length; i++)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawRoundRect(rectSpace + i*(rectWidth + rectSpace*2), rectSpace, rectWidth, rectHeight, arcRect, arcRect);
            g.setColor(Color.black); 
            g.drawString(Numbers[i], rectSpace + textX + i*(rectWidth + rectSpace*2), textY + rectSpace);
        }
    }

    public void setNumbers(String[] pNumbers)
    {
        //Stock les numbres choisis
        Numbers = pNumbers;
    }

    public void changeColor(Color pColor)
    {
        //Change the background color
    }
}
```

Comment: *"i would need to to stock each rectangle and text inside a var to be able to change the color of the rectangle and read the number that is written inside it.*" - Why so procedural? A rectangle class would also do fine :)

Comment: Well, I didn't know that there was such a thing, but if I can use a rounded rectangle class when I draw them and stock that rounded rectangle, could you show me how?

Comment: I can think of some easy, maybe even cheeky solutions. Probably not the best way, but I will definetely post it as an answer soon. - Maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the cleanest way, but you could create a new class that has a method that just draws the wished shape. An ArrayList of the instances of this class, some getters and setters and your problem with all the variables is solved. The constructor's parameters will be `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, `color`, `text` and `font`. Set the corresponding variables and use the getters in the `draw()` method (the one that paints the "shape"). To proof the concept: Below is an example using your code - The second rectangle will be red, because we call `rectangles.get(1).setColor(Color.RED);`. - You can do things like that with any of the instances using the setters. I think everything else in the code is pretty self-explanatory, except the centering of the text... That was just trial and error, TBH :D

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example extends JPanel {

    String[] numbers;
    ArrayList<RoundedRectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<RoundedRectangle>();

    public Example() {
        numbers = new String[] { "12", "3", "5" };
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            RoundedRectangle rr = new RoundedRectangle(100 + i * 100, 100, 50, 50, Color.BLUE, numbers[i],
                    new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 25));
            rectangles.add(rr);
        }
        rectangles.get(1).setColor(Color.RED);
        System.out.println(rectangles.get(1).getColor());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.size(); i++) {
            rectangles.get(i).draw(g2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new Example());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public class RoundedRectangle {

        int x;
        int y;
        int width;
        int height;
        Color color;
        String text;
        Font font;

        public RoundedRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color, String text, Font font) {

            setX(x);
            setY(y);
            setWidth(width);
            setHeight(height);
            setColor(color);
            setText(text);
            setFont(font);

        }

        public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {

            g2.setColor(getColor());
            g2.drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height, 15, 15);

            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics(getFont());
            int width = metrics.stringWidth(getText());
            int height = metrics.getHeight() - metrics.getAscent();
            g2.setFont(getFont());
            g2.drawString(getText(), getX() + getWidth() / 2 - width / 2, getY() + getHeight() / 2 + height);

        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public Font getFont() {
            return font;
        }

        public void setFont(Font font) {
            this.font = font;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: My personal preference would be to make use of the `Rectangle` class itself in your `RoundedRectangle` class to store the bounds, but that's because I'm lazy ;)